# Dropping article title from references without redefining bibstyle

Tags: beamer, bibtex, bibliographies

In the bibliography, how can I drop the titles from the references? For every entry, I want only author names, journal name and year

MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, 10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,mathtools}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\newcommand\footcite[1]{\footnote{\bibentry{#1}}}\usepackage{graphicx}



\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\definecolor{byublue}{RGB}{0 34 85}%added
\definecolor{mydarkgray}{RGB}{64 64 64}%added

\usecolortheme[named=MidnightBlue]{structure}%added
\usetheme{Montpellier}%Montpellier originally
\useoutertheme{tree}%added
\useinnertheme{circles}%added
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}




\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif


\begin{document}
\nobibliography{bibliography_phd_journal_key}

\section{Introduction} 


\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
Some text \footcite{titanath2008p165326}
\end{center}
\end{frame} 





\end{document}
```

Comment: How many entries of type `@article` are in your beamer-based references section? If there are just a handful, you could consider hand-editing the `.bbl` file to eliminate the `title` fields in question.

Comment: There are quite a few.. so ultimately I took help of makebst ...

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine the command used by `bibentry` to print the entry so that the second block is dropped.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\newcommand\footcite[1]{\footnote{\bibentry{#1}}}\usepackage{graphicx}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\definecolor{byublue}{RGB}{0 34 85}%added
\definecolor{mydarkgray}{RGB}{64 64 64}%added

\usecolortheme[named=MidnightBlue]{structure}%added
\usetheme{Montpellier}%Montpellier originally
\useoutertheme{tree}%added
\useinnertheme{circles}%added
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif

\makeatletter
\def\BR@c@bibitem#1 #2\newblock#3\newblock #4 \par{%
{\let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
      \expandafter \gdef\csname BR@r@#1\@extra@b@citeb\endcsname
      {\BR@nodot#2\newblock #4\relax.\relax\relax}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nobibliography{bibliography_phd_journal_key}

\section{Introduction} 

\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    Some text \footcite{titanath2008p165326}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This assumes that the entry in the `.bbl` file has the form

```
\bibitem[Author, 2002]{titanath2008p165326}
Author, A. (2002).
\newblock Title to be removed.
\newblock {\em Jour. J.}
```

with the title delimeted by `\newblock` commands.  This was produced by `bibtex` in your case from the entry

```
@Article{titanath2008p165326,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {Title to be removed},
  journal =  {Jour. J.},
  year =     2002
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will also remove the title from `book` entries, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @AlanMunn The OP only mentions journal entries.  `biblatex` would be a much better way to go for this in general.

Comment: I agree that `biblatex` is the way to go here. I was just pointing out the lack of generality of this as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve what the OP asks for is with [Bibulous](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/) instead of BibTeX or Biblatex. In this case, removing the title from all `article` entries in the reference list is as simple as removing the `<title>` variable from the corresponding template. For example, if the existing `articles` template (inside the Bibulous-format BST file) has the form

```
article = <au>, \enquote{<title>,} \textit{<journal>} \textbf{<volume>}...
          : [<startpage>--<endpage>|<startpage>|<eid>|] (<year>).
```

then all that is needed is to replace this with

```
article = <au>, \textit{<journal>} \textbf{<volume>}...
          : [<startpage>--<endpage>|<startpage>|<eid>|] (<year>).
```